# How to keep camera rotation pointed at origin while moving its position in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, camera, rotation

So I want to move my cameras position around in three.js, but as I move it, I want the cameras rotation to automatically update to point at the origin.

So if i have the camera set as:

```
 camera.position.set(25,25,25)
```

I would like the camera.rotation to be updated so that it is facing the world origin.

Comment: Have you tried setting `camera.lookAt(0,0,0)` ?

Comment: Solved my problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the camera to look at or target a specific position in your scene but using the `lookAt()` method - https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.lookAt

In this case, setting `camera.lookAt(0,0,0)` will point to the centre of the 'world'.